# Error: $compile:multidir Multiple Directive Resource Contention

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive that renders a select field on the view. I get the error below.

When I remove the "replace:true", it works well.

```
Error: $compile:multidir
Multiple Directive Resource Contention
Multiple directives [ngModel, ngModel] asking for 'ngModel on: {5}
```

Here is the code:

```
(function () {

function YesNoDecline($timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<select class="form-control" id="{{ ::id }}" name="{{ ::name }}" ng-model="ngModel.$viewValue"> ' +
                  '     <option ng-repeat="obj in data" value="{{ ::obj.value }}">{{ ::obj.text }}</option>' +
                  '</select>',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            name: '@',
            data: '=ds'
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            scope.ngModel = ngModelCtrl;

        }
    };
};

YesNoDecline.$inject = ['$timeout'];
appModule.directive('yesNoDecline', YesNoDecline);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your YesNoDecline directive has `replace: true` set, that directive is bound to the outermost containing element of its template, in this case your `<select>` element. This select element is requesting an ng-model directive.

I assume your calling template has a line like `<yes-no-decline ng-model="myForm.myBool"></yes-no-decline>`. This leads to 2 requests for the ng-model directive on one element, which doesn't work. HTML doesn't let you have 2 identical attributes on an element. There are several ways to make this go away:

- Turn off `replace: true`
- Wrap your `<select>` element with a `<div>`
- Change the require to `require:'^^ng-model'` and your calling code to `<div ng-model="myForm.myBool"><yes-no-decline></yes-no-decline></div>`
- Alter your directive to not require an ng-model, instead just taking another parameter for it. This last option is the only one that lets your directive directly produce the `<select>` element